# reading two consecutive integer and then its weight

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have a program which reads a integer from a file, as given below.

value1 and value2 are to be taken from user.

path file contains the weight of path, lets say weight of path 1 to 3 is 4 and 5 to 6 is 3, then path file will be:

```
path

1 3 4

5 6 1

3 2 1
```

The code is:

```
fp=fopen("path","r");

while(fscanf(fp,"%d",i)==1)
{
  if(((j==value1)&&(i==value2))||((j==value2)&&(i==value1)))
    weight={next value which will be read};
}
```

I want the logic to read the above weight

Also, while scanning the file it should not take the third integer of each line.

For example, if I want path between 1 to3 then it should not scan the 1 or 3 which is in third coloum.

The framing of this doubt is quite difficult, but I will try to make it clear if anybody of you wish to help me.

Comment: Extra semicolon in `while` line? The way you have your code, the `while` loop (1 single line) will read all of the input if there are no read or conversion errors.

Comment: oops sorry...  
There is no semi colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a expert in C language but the third parameter of the function fscanf expected a memory address, if the variable i is a integer, you need to use &i ok?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/

I'm sorry because for anything. lol .

Comment: +1 nicely spotted! @sanketmlad: increase the warning level of your compiler.

Comment: Indeed the third element is the last element, hence even if we can detect a new line and start handling first two elements our work is done..... So even if you know how to detect a new line, then please let me know.